# Will Google find and index my link that has the same color as the background?

Tags: google-search

I am managing a website and I  want a page to be discovered and indexed by Google. However, I cannot make it directly visible to visitors on a page. So, I make the background and link text have the same color. Here is what I have:

```
<a href="my-page" style="display:block;width:5px;height:5px;background-color:#fff;color:#fff;overflow:hidden;">An very interesting page</a>
```

Will this piece of code work? What else I should do?

### Update

I just wanted to know whether this trick works. Actually I have many and unpredictable links like this situation. I cannot go to Google to submit each link.

### Update

If this trick works, do I need to do anything in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Did you know you can submit urls to Google?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether this trick works. Actually I have many links like this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errrr yes... Google doesn't look at the style to know whether to index the page. You can also remove the link and tell Google to index it directly. Look for SEO and page indexation FAQs.

Comment: Hi David, thanks so much for chiming in. I just wanted to know whether this trick works. Actually I have many links like this situation.

Comment: David, if this trick works, do I need to anything in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: It's not a trick. It's how indexing works. You just have to declare the links with Google.

Comment: Never rely on styling to hide information the user cannot see